# Any other Flex service code generation plugins?

Tags: web-services, apache-flex, actionscript, code-generation, wcf-data-services

In Flash Builder 4, there's a setting for what code generator you want to use for the data/services utilities. The only option I have is "Default", and I haven't been able to find if there are any other options out there, and how to use them.

I dislike how the default code generator works, so I'd love to find out how difficult it would be to implement our own, or if there are any better ones out there. So I suppose my question is: does it get better in the latest version of flash builder, or are there any other good alternatives?

Comment: My experience finds code generation lacking.  I know that WebORB had some code generation utilities.  Or you could, in theory, write your own Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

What is your server side technology?   Here is a possible answer if you are using Java.

GraniteDs - http://www.graniteds.org - which is an alternative to BlazeDs includes automatic generation of typed AS3 objects (valueObjects) and AS3 service proxies.   This feature is available as a plugin for Eclipse, Maven and Ant.

See chapter 5 of the GraniteDs documentation.  http://www.graniteds.org/public/docs/2.3.2/docs/reference/en-US/html/graniteds.gas3.html#gas3.overview

Comment: We are using ASP.NET on the server side.